# Basic Maths Game, Python: 'input expected at most 1 arguements, got 4'

Tags: python

I've been working with Python for a little while now, and I decided recently I wanted to make a basic maths game that would choose a random number from a list between 0-9, and make you add them together. If your answer was right, it would say well done, if it was wrong, it would say try again next time.

I'm having a problem with a line of code though, because it comes up with an error message saying:

```
input expected at most 1 arguments, got 4
```

for this line of code:

```
ans=int(input(num1,'+',num2,'= '))
```

I've looked it up several times, and have found answers to the problem, but not in the way I need them. Here is the whole line of code.

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
import random
num1 = random.choice(nums)
num2 = random.choice(nums)
sum = num1+num2
correct_ans = sum
ans=int(input(num1,'+',num2,'= '))
if ans==correct_ans:
    print('Correct, Well Done!')
else:
    print('Wrong, Try Again Next Time!')
```

Comment: *"if I haven't looked hard enough"* - well searching for *"[python] input expected at most 1 arguments"* would have found you multiple duplicates, so I'd say not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Input takes 1 arg

You are passing 4 args to `input` which accepts only 1 argument

```
input(num1,'+',num2,'= ')   # 4 args!
```

try

```
question = '{} + {} ='.format(num1, num2)
input(question)
```

### Putting it all together and discussing about types

```
import random

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

num_1 = random.choice(nums)
num_2 = random.choice(nums)

# This sum is numeric sum not a string concat
correct_ans = num_1 + num_2

# Let's make a question string by concat of our numbers in string format
question = '{} + {} = '.format(num_1, num_2)
ans = input(question)

# At this point ans is still a string so convert
ans = int(ans)

# Now you are comparing two ints
if  ans == correct_ans:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Wrong!')
```

### Test run

```
python math_game.py
3 + 3 = 6
Correct!

python math_game.py
7 + 2 = 1
Wrong!
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I replaced my line with that one, and it seemed fine at first, it ran nicely, giving two random  numbers and I typed in the answer, but it then came up with an error message saying 'NameError: name 'ans' is not defined' ans is no longer used to determine if the answer typed in is correct or not, so where do I go from there?

Comment: Seems you no longer have `ans`. Do you have `ans = input(question)` and converting it to `int` with e.g. `ans = int(ans)` or `ans = int(input(question))` somewhere?

Comment: I just figured it out, I had to change the 'question' to 'ans'. After that it ran nicely, what I did find however, was that rather than adding the number together normally, it was added together like a string. 4 + 1 = 5 came out as wrong. It also seems to not work when I put the numbers together as a string (4+1=41), it always comes out as wrong.

Comment: If you add two `int` together you'll get an `int`, if you "add" two `str` (strings) together you will be concatenating them, in my `question` variable, they are concatenated to show the text for the question, when you calculate the correct answer, you should be adding two `int`

Comment: I don't quite understand, sorry, anyway I put it, the answer comes out as wrong, do I have to change the question variable in order for it to work?

Comment: OK hold on I'll make a complete example with explanations about types :)

Comment: @CDChaser There, hope this helps you understanding what's going on, if it does please accept the answer

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped me understand what I've done wrong and how I should have done, once again, thanks, and I hope I wasn't being too difficult!